# Comparison Hash, MAC, Signatures, Certificates

Tags: hash, signature, authentication, certificates

I saw a table comparing Hash/Mac/Signatures in [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5646/what-are-the-differences-between-a-digital-signature-a-mac-and-a-hash) post.

I was wondering if I can integrate digital certificates into it like this:

|  | Hash | MAC | Signature | Certificate + Signature |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Integrity | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Authentication | No | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Non-repudiation | No | No | Yes | Yes |
| Identification | No | No | No | Yes |
| Kind of keys | None | Symmetric | Asymmetric | Asymmetric |

Does this is make sense to you?

Do you see *trust* in the same category of security goals like *Integrity* etc. ?

*Edit: Changed 'Trust' to 'Identification', Added Signature to the certificate column*

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by 'Trust'?  I can think of several possible meanings; which one are you thinking of?

Comment: Trust in the sense of that the user explicitly trusted an entity, e.g. Microsoft, and transivitly everyone they trust. So the user can be sure that she directly or indirectly trusts the entity she is talking to. Does this makes sense? Do you have a better word for what security goal certificates provide?

Comment: Identification/Authorization, perhaps?  Certificates can both bind a public key to an identity (identification), as well as give the holder of the private key certain rights (e.g. he can be the host to https::amazon.com), that is, authorization

Comment: Also note that certificates don't necessarily provide "integrity or nonrepudiation"; a certificate can hold a public encryption key; that tells you how to encrypt something to that entity, but I don't see how you can describe it as providing integrity or nonrepudiation...

Comment: Identification is a good word I think. Authorization follows then logically out of the identification and is more specific. You are right, a certificate alone does not provide integrity or nonrepudiation of an attached message.

Comment: So if I replace "Trust" with "identification" and add to the Certificate also a Signature to provide integrity and nonrepudiation, the table would make sense for you?